# How Do I Set Doc Without Overwriting Array In Firestore React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a to-do style app in react. I'm using firebase/firestore for my data.  My users collection and document look like this:

[image]

Here's my `createLabel` function:

```
const createLabel = async () => {
  setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
    labels: { ...labels, id: fifa },
  });
};
```

This function basically erases everything in thing in the labels collection and adds only id:fifa like so:

[image]

I'm wondering how I can somehow save a copy of the current collection, and re-write it with a new object (2) that would contain cards: [{}] and id:"fifa" ?

I saved the entire labels array into state called labels and tried to use the spread operator to push the new id:fifa into the labels array but I'm not getting it where I need it to be.

Any help in achieving this would be appreciated.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: To use Firestore terminology correctly, `labels` is an array typed document field, and `users` is your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug alluded to in his comments, you'll want to do:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
  labels: arrayUnion({ id: fifa })
}, { merge: true })
```

Here:

- `arrayUnion` ensures that your values get merged with the existing items in the `labels` field. Note that this only adds the item if the exact same value isn't in the array yet.
- `{ merge: true }` ensures that the other fields don't get overwritten either.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Appreciate the breakdown.